# How to allow google-chart polymer to load data with basic authentication?

Tags: polymer, basic-authentication

How to allow google-chart polymer to load data with basic authentication when using the data=url ?

Answer (score 0):

the data=url pattern is for simple use cases.
Under the hood it uses `iron-ajax` but you can't really access it in order to add authentication headers/credentials.
Better just to use `iron-ajax`/`fetch` directly and pass the data to `google-chart`.